Can hazard pointer proposed by Maged M. Michael prevent ABA problem?
UPDATE:
As far as I concerned, "another thread could potentially remove and then re-insert the node between lines 4 and 4b" means that a node can be removed, modified, and reinserted to the same position before being fully reclaimed by another thread between lines 4 and 4b, leading to a potential ABA problem where the node's content changes even though its address remains the same.

I'm reading a thesis by Maged M. Michael that introduces hazard pointer.
Here is an Enqueue function that uses hazard pointer:
//FIFO queue algorithm, stripped of memory management code
structure NodeType { Data:DataType; Next:*NodeType; }
//Shared variables
Head,Tail:*NodeType;
//Initially both Head and Tail point to a dummy node

//hp0 is private ptr to 2 of the thread's hazard ptrs

Enqueue(data: DataType) {
1. node <- NewNode();
2. node.Data <- data;
3. node.Next <- null;
   while true {
4.   t <- Tail;
4a:  *hp0 <- t;
4b:  if (Tail ≠ t) continue;
5.   next <- t.Next
6.   if (Tail ≠ t) continue;
7.   if (next ≠ null) {CAS(&Tail, t, next); continue;}
8.   if CAS(&t.next, null, node) break;
   }
9. CAS(&Tail, t, node);
}

Without lines 4a and 4b, accessing the node at line 5 could be an access hazard because another thread might have removed and reclaimed the node *t after the current thread executed line 4.
Access hazard: A thread tries to access a node that has already been freed by another thread.
The author says that Lines 4a and 4b guarantees safe memory reclamation and ABA prevention.

line 4a: The thread assigns the address of the referenced node to a hazard pointer

line 4b: Then, it validates that node is safe. If not, it skips over the hazards and tries again.


I understand how lines 4a and 4b guarantees safe memory reclamation, but I don't see how they guarantees ABA prevention.
The author also mentions that another thread could potentially remove and then re-insert the node between lines 4 and 4b. However, the author says this is acceptable because it doesn't violate a condition in Section 3.3.
In other words, the author acknowledges the ABA problem (node removal and re-insertion) might occur, but as long as a specific condition from Section 3.3 holds, it's okay.
Section 3.3 Condition:

Therefore, the condition that an associated algorithm must satisfy is that whenever a thread is holding a hazardous reference to a node, it must be the case that at least one of the thread’s hazard pointers has been continuously holding that reference from a time when the node was definitely safe for the thread. Note that this condition implies that no thread can create a new hazardous reference to a node while it is retired.

I don't understand how this condition relates to preventing the ABA problem at lines 4a and 4b.

Any algorithm that solves the memory reclamation problem is also a solution for the ABA problem under the assumption that objects/nodes/allocations are only re-used (e.g., re-inserted) after they have been successfully reclaimed.

@mpoeter I cannot relate your answer to original question. Can you please explain it in more detail? I mean, the author doesn't make the assumption you said and still claim the ABA problem in prevented.

Any algorithm that solves the memory reclamation problem is also a solution for the ABA problem under the assumption that objects/nodes/allocations are only re-used (e.g., re-inserted) after they have been successfully reclaimed.
You have not included the code of the Deqeue operation in your question, so here it goes:
   while true {
11:  h <- Head;
11a: *hp0 <- h;
11b: if (Head != h) continue;
12:  t <- Tail
13:  next <- h.Next
13a: *hp1 <- next
14:  if (Head != h) continue;
15:  if (next == null) return EMPTY;
16:  if (h == t) { CAS(&Tail, t, next); continue; }
17:  data <- next.Data;
18:  if (CAS(&Head, h, next) break;
  }
19: RetireNode(h); return data;
}

The ABA problem relies on the reuse of addresses, so essentially a node that has previously been part of the queue must be reused and reinserted into the queue while some other thread has not yet realized that it has been removed in the meantime. In that case the thread would wrongly assume that it still sees the correct and unchanged state. The memory reclamation algorithm prevents that, because no node can be reused before it is reclaimed. By retiring the node in line 19 in Dequeue we mark it as ready for reclamation, but it will only be reclaimed once all threads that may currently see it (i.e., that have a hazard pointer referencing it) have finished their operation. And as long as the node has not been reclaimed, its memory cannot be reused by NewNode. Therefore this prevents the ABA problem by delaying reuse of nodes until a point when it is safe.
